# How to disable example schema and remove "Send an Empty Value" in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I am new to OpenAPI and I want to know how I can do a couple of things in Swagger UI:

1. I want to disable the Example Schema part of my request:

[image]

This is the OpenAPI YAML code I am using:

```yaml
responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/vnd.ms-excel:
              schema:
                 type: string
                 format: binary
              examples:
                sampleFile:
                  summary: Ambient.xlsx
                  externalValue: 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1twQkxo-BIQ-Fv98rJVe_tqAXpLwHsvjP'
```

2. How do I remove the "Send an Empty Value" option for my file upload ?

[image]

The OpenAPI code I am using is:

```yaml
requestBody:
        description: Upload a document
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
            encoding:
              file:
                contentType: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

I have tried `required: true` but it has no effect.